# someone asked if we have something or had something?

Tags: tense, reported-speech

Which one is correct?

> 1 Last night, one of our neighbors knocked on our door and asked if we *had* a pair of pliers to lend.

> 2 Last night, one of our neighbors knocked on our door and asked if we *have* a pair of pliers to lend.

Comment: I think 2nd one is incorrect.

Comment: It's usual to use the past tense in this kind of context, even though the speaker's household still own the pliers.

Answer (score 1):

Correct: 1 Last night, one of our neighbors **knocked** on our door and **asked** if we **had** a pair of pliers to lend.